# Почему default-аргумент не перезаписывается?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Скажите пожалуйста, почему в следующем коде на третьем вызове функции f() значение l становится [0, 1]

```
def f(x, l=[]):
    print('=====', l)
    for i in range(x):
        l.append(i*i)
    print(l)


f(2)
f(3, [3, 2, 1])
f(3)
```

Вывод:

```
===== []
[0, 1]
===== [3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 4]
===== [0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 4]
```

Есть ли этому логическое объяснение? Это можно запомнить, но хотелось бы именно понять.

Ход моей мысли такой:

1. функция f() при первом вызове заполняет l значением [0, 1]
2. при втором вызове функции f() значение l перезаписывается. То есть
   предыдущее значение удаляется
3. теоретически при третьем вызове в l должно содержаться или [] или
   [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 4]
4. НО там содержится [0, 1]. ОТКУДА?..

Comment: замените `print('=====', l)`  на `print('=====', l, id(l))` и посмотрите что происходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> при втором вызове функции f() значение l перезаписывается. То есть
>   предыдущее значение удаляется

Нет. Как раз в этом Вы и заблуждаетесь. Значение `l` остаётся прежним, а функция использует переданное значение.

> НО там содержится [0, 1]. ОТКУДА?..

Изменённое стандартное значение `l` после первого вызова функции.

---

Чтобы подтвердить мною сказанное, давайте дизассемблируем код (последние 2 вызова):

```py
 10          20 LOAD_NAME                0 (f)
             22 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             24 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             26 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             28 LOAD_CONST               4 (1)
             30 BUILD_LIST               3
             32 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             34 POP_TOP

 11          36 LOAD_NAME                0 (f)
             38 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             40 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             42 POP_TOP
```

Обратите внимание на инструкцию `CALL_FUNCTION`. Её описание:

> **CALL_FUNCTION**(*argc*)
>   Вызывает вызываемый объект с позиционными аргументами. *argc* указывает количество позиционных аргументов.

---

Когда Вы вызывали функцию, заменяя стандартный аргумент, происходило следующее:

```py
             32 CALL_FUNCTION            2
#                                       ^^^
```

`Python` для вызова брал 2 аргумента из стека. `l` вообще не участвует при вызове и тем более не перезаписывается.

Когда Вы не передавали второй аргумент, `Python` брал его из объекта функции (брал `l`):

```py
             40 CALL_FUNCTION            1
#                                       ^^^
```

Comment: Хороший ответ. Правильно ли я понимаю, что в данном случае, если передаётся второй параметр, то используется именно он, если нет, то берётся тот, который остался от выполнения первой операции?

Comment: @Denis640Kb Да, Вы правильно понимаете.

Comment: Спасибо, а то я что-то тоже запутался было )))

Comment: Думаю, объяснение в комментариях к вопросу от S.Nick проще для понимания :)